# How to create a git project from an existing maven project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I have a local maven project. Now I want to put it into a git repository. I think I first need to create a local git project and then push all to the remote repository. Is there a way to do this in Eclipse? I have the egit plugin in Eclipse.

Tried the following step:

```
1) Create a local new Git repository and add it to this view
2) There are 3 options:
   * Import Maven Proejcts
   * Import existing proejcts
   * Import as a general project
```

None of these seem works. This should be a very typical use case. First, you create a maven locally, without git. At some point, you want to put it into a git repository and collaborate with others. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Unless you absolutely want to do this in Eclipse - it's probably easier and quicker to do this from the command line. Open a terminal/shell/command window in your project directory and then do the following:

```
git init
```

That's it... You will now have a local empty Git repository.

Before you commit anything, think about adding a `.gitignore` file to ignore files that don't belong in the repo. Here's a good starting point: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore

Please note that this ignores the `.project` and `.classpath` files - some people prefer to share these with other developers.

Once you have added some files and committed them, you can add a *remote* to point to the remote repository.

In the long run, it makes sense to get familiar with the command line, even when using an IDE like Eclipse. Many things are easier from the IDE once it's set up (like reviewing changes, history, etc.), but simple tasks like adding files, committing changes or similar are sometimes easier done from the command line.

Comment: You meant, go to my maven root directory and execute "git init"? My maven project is under /user/workspace/project.

Comment: Then what's the next step to push it a remote repository?

Comment: From command line, you can use `git remote add origin http://...`, then `git push origin master`. Both of these should also be available from within Eclipse.

Comment: You need to provide the URL of your remote repo, e.g. from a project you created on GitHub or a similar provider. See here for more help: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/

Comment: error: src refspec master does not match any. After I executed the git push.

Answer (score 6):

Right clicking the project, *Team*, *Share project…* allows you to initialize a Git repository for your project.

Comment: after doing as above, I cannot run the project. This error comes. `Error: Could not find or load main class` how to fix it

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya: Using  _Share project…_ should have no influence on your run configurations. I guess you have some other problem. Try to right click your main class and then _Run As_, _Java Application_.

Comment: had to restart eclipse to run the project again. What is the reason behind it

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya: Sorry, but I have no idea what the reason may have been. If this occurs often to you, you may [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)…

Comment: For the case someone else gets here. Sometimes Eclipse trusts the class files are compiled while they are not, maybe the .class files have been deleted. It has autobuild enabled by default but it doesn't know build needs running. Click Project -> Clean -> Clean and it will build the project again after cleaning, if you didn't disable Project -> Autobuild.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect to get it working with the following steps: 
1. right-click on your project, select Team → Share Project → Git
2. Commit Changes
2. push to remote

Other workaround might be, import as git project, right klick on it -> configure -> enable maven

Comment: what's "add changes", and from where to "import Maven project"? Have you done this before? Thanks.

Comment: Modified the answer slightly

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command with passing your project directory

git init