# Error: Could not find or load main class eclipse git after creating a repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I have very simple project that I just started.
I only have this class and it works fine (nothing to do but print)
[image]

Now I want to share my project, so I did the following steps: 
right click on project >> Team >> Share Project ..

I got the following window - [image]

So I pressed on create, gave a name to the new local repository and than pressed finish and finish again.

Now Im facing the error - 
**Error: Could not find or load main class encryptor.Encryptor**

What did I do wrong and more important how can I fix it?

Using -

Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
JavaSE-1.8 (jre 1.8.0_73)

Comment: Sorry for the downvotes, this is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: To make it an even better question, can you edit it with the exact version of Eclipse, Java and Git used in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializing a git repo should have no influence on your current Eclipse project settings (.classpath and .project)

But this error [has been seen before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30995379/6309), and the simple solution was to restart Eclipse.
Check if the error persists then.

The [OP Paz Reingold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4907214/paz-reingold) adds in the comments:

> After looking over the problem again, I realize something mess up after I create new local repository, because I switched the workspace and than it did not recognize the JRE System Libary.
>   I needed to add it again (Can check it by right click on `project >> properties >> Java Build Path >> Libaries`)

Comment: After looking over the problem again, I realize something mess up after I create new local repository, because I switched the workspace and than it didnt recognize the JRE System Libary so I needed to add it again (Can check it by right click on project >> properties >> Java Build Path >> Libaries  )

Comment: @PazReingold Well spotted: that actually will help others. Don't forget to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone that had the same issue as me. The way I solved it was by going to the Java build path and deleting a corrupt JUnit jar.

So,

Step 1. Right click on your project and then click on properties

Step 2. Select Java Build Path

Step 3. Select Libraries and see if there is a corrupt jar marked red. For me, it was JUnit.jar